# If $\bar X_n\leq X_n$ for every $n$ then the associated counting processes are such that $\bar N(t) \geq N(t)$ for every $t$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> $\{X_n, n\geq 1\}$ is a renewal process. Let, there exists an $\alpha>0$ such that $P(X_n\geq \alpha)>0$. Now, define another related renewal process, $\{\bar X_n, n\geq 1\}$ by,
>     \begin{equation}
> \bar X_n=
> \begin{cases}
>   0, & \text{if}\ X_n <\alpha \\
>   \alpha, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
>   \end{equation}
>   For, $n\ge 1$, let $S_n = X_1+\dots + X_n$ and $\bar S_n = \bar X_1+\dots + \bar X_n$. Also, let, $N(t) = \max \{n\mid S_n \leq t\}$ and $\bar N(t) = \max \{n\mid \bar S_n \leq t\}$
>
> Show that, $\bar N(t) \geq N(t)$.

**What I did:** It is easy to see that $\bar X_n \leq X_n$, so $\bar S_n\leq S_n$. We also know that $\{N(t)\geq n\}\Leftrightarrow\{S_n\leq t\}$.

Comment: Well, $\bar S_n\leq S_n$ hence $\{N(t)\geq n\}=\{S_n\leq t\}\subseteq\{\bar S_n\leq t\}=\{\bar N(t)\geq n\}$. And if $\{N(t)\geq n\}\subseteq\{\bar N(t)\geq n\}$ for every $n$, then $\bar N(t)\ge N(t)$ almost surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braces $\{$ and $\}$ in your last statement should not be there. Then we get:$$N(t)\geq n\iff S_n\leq t$$as it should.

Combining this with $\overline S_n\leq S_n$ we find:$$N(t)\geq n\implies \overline S_n\leq t$$or - on base of $\overline N(t)\geq n\iff \overline S_n\leq t$ - equivalently:$$N(t)\geq n\implies \overline N(t)\geq n\tag1$$

This  for every $n$, so it implies that: $$\overline N(t)\geq N(t)\tag2$$

---

Formally pick out an arbitrary $\omega\in\Omega$ an let it be that $n=N(t)(\omega)$. Then $N(t)(\omega)\geq n$ so according to $(1)$ we have $\overline N(t)(\omega)\geq n=N(t)(\omega)$. This proves that $\overline N(t)(\omega)\geq N(t)(\omega)$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$ or shortly that $(2)$ is valid.